# How to reset report_count to initial value in ireport after 10 records in ireports

Tags: jasper-reports

I have to reset the report_count varialbe to the initial value. Initially report_count  value is 1.. after 10 records I have to reset this to 1 again.
And also I have to print like 001, 002.... 010. 
can u please suggest me.

Comment: Please tag ireport or jasper. This is nothing to do with jquery/ajax/javascript. Also please show some code which you've tried.

Comment: In report output I will get no. of records with sequence like 1,2,3.. 10.. For this I am using $V{REPORT_COUNT}. after 10 records again the sequence should be start from 1, i.e., for 11th record sequence is 1. How can i do this in ireport?

Comment: @deepthi You can add the variable and use it

Comment: Can u please tell me in detail.. @Alex

Answer (score 0):

Create a new variable, set its class to String, Calculation - Nothing, ResetTipe - None, IncrementType - None and VariableExpression to

```
($V{REPORT_COUNT}.intValue()%10)>0?("00"+$V{REPORT_COUNT}.intValue()%10):("010")
```

and use this variable instead wherever you want to show the page number.